# Adjust Zoom Level if Geolocation is Successful?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

How can I adjust the zoom level within the function if the geolocation is successful (success)?

```
function createMap(lat, lng) {
var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), 
  zoom: 12,
  scrollwheel: false,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

function initialize() {
if(navigator.geolocation) {
  success = function(position) {
    createMap(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  };
  error = function() { createMap(99.648493, -99.410812); }

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
 }
}
```

Comment: Hope you can pass one more argument to createmap called zoom level. If success one zoomlevel and if error then other zoom level.

Comment: also if map variable is global you could just call map.setZoom after createMap

Comment: If you add the definition of `createMap` to your code listing, I'm sure someone will suggest something along the lines of @Matrix's comment.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks. sorry I am really green when it comes to JavaScript and Google Maps API for that matter, forgive the sloppiness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the following code to change zoom level based on geolocation:

```
 function createMap(lat, lng, zoomVal) {
 var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),    
zoom: zoomVal,   
scrollwheel: false,  
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
}; 
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);  
function initialize() { 
if(navigator.geolocation) {  
 success = function(position) {    
 createMap(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude,15);  
 };   
error = function() {
 createMap(99.648493, -99.410812,12); 
}    
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);  
} 
}
```